# How to randomly display images in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a array of images that I want them to be displayed randomly in UI.

Tried below code in typescrip, but getting error for innerHTML.

```
randomPic(){
    this.randomNum= Math.floor(Math.random() * this.myPix.length);
    console.log(this.randomNum)
    return  document.getElementById('myPicture').innerHTML= '<img src="'+this.myPix[randomNum]+'" />'; 
  }
```

Can somebody help me that where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Can you share your html as well ? And as you are using angular, why not use data binding ? Generate your random number in your TS and use it in your html.

Comment: Make sure the images in src are present in the same folder as the HTML with very JS that you have shared. Also you are missing the image extension in your src attribute like .png. 
I believe with this kind of problem Browser development tools and simplest inside into you running code: console.log(''), would get you where you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `document.getElementById` in an angular context. Usually, what you want can be achieved by binding data from your component to your template (and vice versa).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-foobar',
  template: `
    <img [src]="myPix[randomNumber]" />
  `,
})
export class FoobarComponent {
  readonly myPix = [
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/200',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/350',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/400',
  ];

  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.myPix.length);
}
```

In this example we make use of [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax#binding-types-and-targets) (`[src]`).